# Particle filter/SMC - dynamic rotation in ICA (independent component analysis)

Tags: time-series, latent-variable, state-space-models, particle-filter

I struggle with the applicability of the bootstrap particle filter within dynamic rotations in independent component analysis.

To be clear, suppose the following:
$$Y_{t} = R(\delta_{t})\epsilon_{t}$$
$$\epsilon_{1, t} \sim t(5) \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$$
$$\epsilon_{2, t} \sim t(6) \sqrt{\frac{4}{6}}$$
$$R(\delta_{t}) = \begin{bmatrix} cos\;\delta_{t} & -sin\;\delta_{t} \\ sin\;\delta_{t} & cos\;\delta_{t} \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\delta_{t} = \phi\delta_{t-1} + v_{t}$$
$$v_{t} \sim N(0, 1)$$

In this case the process of the rotation angle $\delta_{t}$ is not observable. I would like to get an estimate of the unknown parameter $\phi$ and the filtering result for the rotation angles. Now, because $R(\delta_{t})$ is orthogonal we have that:

$$R(\delta_{t})^{T}Y_{t} = \epsilon_{t}$$

$$(cos\;\delta_{t})y_{1, t} + (sin\;\delta_{t})y_{2, t} \sim t(5)*\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$$
$$(-sin\;\delta_{t})y_{1, t} + (cos\;\delta_{t})y_{2, t} \sim t(6)*\sqrt{\frac{4}{6}}$$

I use this fact to evaluate the importance weights of each draw:
$$w_{t}^{(i)} = g_{1}((cos\;\delta_{t})y_{1, t} + (sin\;\delta_{t})y_{2, t}) * g_{2}((-sin\;\delta_{t})y_{1, t} + (cos\;\delta_{t})y_{2, t})$$

These weights are then used for the resampling step. $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ are the standardized t-distributions with 5 and 6 degrees of freedom respectively.

**The problem is that the computed weights are very similar and hence the resampling step does not filter out "unlikely" draws for the rotation angle $\delta_{t}$...**

**Does anyone know if I am missing something? I am pretty new to particle filtering and independent component analysis.**

**If it helps, I can provide an R script with simulated data and the implementation of the particle filter.**